# MapPageRoute additional parameters in URL

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I'm using MapPageRoute (ASP.NET 4) for supporting friendly urls in a multi language web site.

I want to be able to pass additional parameters along with the ones defined in the MapPageRoute.

In the example above, I need to determine the requested language according to the URL:
(if it is "Accessories", the page should be in English, if it is "Accessoires" - the page should be in French):

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Accessory fr",
           "Accessoires/{accessory_name}",
           "~/Accessory.aspx?lang=fr"
        );

    routes.MapPageRoute(
       "Accessory en",
       "Accessories/{accessory_name}",
       "~/Accessory.aspx?lang=en"
    );
```

So, no problem with the  requested accessory name, it is read by using `Page.RouteData.Values["accessory_name"]`, but how can I read the `lang` parameter ?

I cannot use `Request["lang"]` since it doesn't give me the requested results.
Somehow, the `?lang=xx` is not taken .

Any other idea, how can I pass additional parameter, assuming this parameter is not found explicitly in the URL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is to pass additional parameters to your route handler(page), you can set DataTokens property,

```
Route reportRoute = new Route("Accessoires/{accessory_name}", new PageRouteHandler("~/Accessory.aspx"));
reportRoute.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary { { "lang", "en" } };
routes.Add(reportRoute);
```

You could access this in your handler(page),

```
string lang = (string)Page.RouteData.DataTokens["lang"];
```

Check msdn,
[Route.DataTokens Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.datatokens.aspx)